# LOF, LOT space between text and page number from page 100 on to short

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I try to have a longer space between the Text in List of Figure/Table and the page number. From page 100 on the space is to short. How can I adjust this?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,reqno]{amsbook} 

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % Kodierung
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel} % Sprache


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%list of figures Abstand Zahl und Text
\makeatletter
\def\l@figure{\@tocline{0}{3pt plus2pt}{0pt}{3pc}{}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
%\def\l@table{\@tocline{0}{Abstnd_zur_nächsten_zeilept plus2pt}{Abstanz_zur_linken_Seitept}{Abstand_fig_nr_text}{Text_fig_nr_text}}
\def\l@table{\@tocline{0}{3pt plus2pt}{0pt}{3pc}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument

\begin{table}[p]
    \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \end{tabular}
\caption{This is a table with a very very very very very long caption.}
\end{table}

\listoftables 

\end{document}
```

This generates this LOT:
[image]

Comment: Do you really need this `\l@table` redefinition? Omitting it would produce a better spacing!

Comment: I use this to have a larger space between the figure number and text. If I don’t use this I get the figure number written on top of the text. And it does not change anything on the space between text and page number…

Comment: Has nobody an idea, how to solve this?